# Azure Terraform Build Generic Components using Infrastructure as Code

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to Terraform and Azure. I am trying to build a Resource Group / Resources using Terraform. Below is the design for the same.

[image]

I have written Terraform code to build Log Analytics workspace and Automation account.
Now below are my questions :

1. Cost Mgmt / Azure Monitor / Network Watcher / Defender for Cloud ? Can I build all these using Terraform code in this resource group or they need to manually built from Azure portal. When we create any resource on the left hand side options like Cost estimator / management are already available. Does that mean they can be easily selected from there on usage and no need to build from Terraform code ?
2. How does we apply Role Entitlement / Policy Assignment from Terraform code ?

Here is my code what I have written to build Automation account / Log Analytics

```
terraform {

  required_version = ">=0.12"
  
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "management" {
 
  # Mandatory resource attributes
  name     = "k8s-log-analytics-test"
  location = "eastus"
  
}

resource "random_id" "workspace" {
  keepers = {
    # Generate a new id each time we switch to a new resource group
    group_name = azurerm_resource_group.management.name
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "management" {
  

  # Mandatory resource attributes
  name                = "k8s-workspace-${random_id.workspace.hex}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.management.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.management.name

  # Optional resource attributes 
  retention_in_days          = 30
  sku                        = "PerGB2018"


}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "management" {

  # Mandatory resource attributes
  solution_name         = "mgmyloganalytsolution"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.management.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.management.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.management.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.management.name
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"
  }


}

resource "azurerm_automation_account" "management" {
  
  # Mandatory resource attributes
  name                = "mgmtautomationaccount"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.management.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.management.name 
  sku_name = "Basic"
 

}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_linked_service" "management" {

  # Mandatory resource attributes
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.management.name
  workspace_id        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.management.id
  read_access_id  = azurerm_automation_account.management.id
 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cost Mgmt / Azure Monitor / Network Watcher / Defender for Cloud ? Can
> I build all these using Terraform code in this resource group or they
> need to manually built from Azure portal. When we create any resource
> on the left hand side options like Cost estimator / management are
> already available. Does that mean they can be easily selected from
> there on usage and no need to build from Terraform code ?

***Yes , you can create Network Watcher , Azure Monitor resources & Cost Management  using terraform resource blocks as `azurerm_network_watcher` , `azurerm_network_watcher_flow_log` ,`azurerm_monitor_metric_alert` `...` , `azurerm_resource_group_cost_management_export`, `azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group` etc. `Defender for Cloud` can't be built from terraform . Yes you are correct , cost management ,monitoring etc are also available on portal but there is a need for its resources to be created like budget alert etc. for simplification it has been added as a blade in portal.***

---

> How does we apply Role Entitlement / Policy Assignment from Terraform
> code ?

***You can use `azurerm_role_assignment` to assign built-in roles and use `azurerm_role_definition` to create a custom role and then assign it . For Policy assignment you can use this `azurerm_resource_policy_assignment` and remediate using `azurerm_policy_insights_remediation`.***

---

**For all the azure resource block you can refer the [`Official Registry Documentation of Terraform AzureRM Provider`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) & [`Terraform AzureAD Provider`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs).**